# Por qué cuándo uso una variable creada en un sp de postgres, la indentifica cómo columna y no cómo variable?, y, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, stored-procedure, postgis

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado :

tengo tres variables declaradas:

```
rec record;
n1_p numeric;
ciudad_base Bigint;
```

luego uso un cursor implicito para recorrer una tabla que consta de puntos con latitude y longitude

```
BEGIN
FOR rec IN
    (SELECT SP.*
    FROM routing.service_point SP
        INNER JOIN routing.service_point_by_route SP_R ON (SP_R.service_point_id = SP.service_point_id)
        INNER JOIN routing.route R ON (R.route_id = SP_R.route_id)
    WHERE R.study_id = var_study_id
    AND R.work_time = -1 
    AND R.route_time = -1 
    AND R.route_distance = -1
    AND R.route_id = var_route_id)          
LOOP
    ciudad_base :=
        (SELECT 
            (SELECT id_2 
             FROM geografias.nivel3 
             WHERE public.st_contains(geografias.nivel3.geog :: geometry,
                public.st_transform(
                    public.st_geometryfromtext('POINT(' || c.longitude || ' ' || c.latitude || ')', 4326), 4326
                ) :: geometry
             )
        )
        FROM routing.city c
            JOIN routing.route r ON (c.city_id = r.city_id)
        WHERE r.route_id =  var_route_id);

    n1_p := (53); /*(SELECT id_0 
        FROM geografias.nivel1 
        WHERE public.st_contains(geografias.nivel1.geog :: geometry,
            public.st_transform(
                public.st_geometryfromtext('POINT(' || rec.longitude || ' ' || rec.latitude || ')', 4326), 4326
            ) :: geometry
        )) :: numeric;
        */
    RAISE NOTICE '(%)', n1_p;

    CREATE VIEW v_nivel_2 AS 
    SELECT gid, id_0, id_1, name_1, geog 
    FROM geografias.nivel2 
    WHERE id_0 = n1_p :: numeric;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END
```

la variable ciudad_base, la uso para saber el código de una ciudad *xy*

lo que deseo realizar, es crear una vista con la información de una consulta de otra tabla dónde encuentro otro nivel geográfico,

```
CREATE VIEW v_nivel_2 AS 
    SELECT gid, id_0, id_1, name_1, geog 
    FROM geografias.nivel2 
    WHERE id_0 = n1_p :: numeric;
```

dónde la varible **np_1** me define elcriterio de búsqueda en la tabla **geografias.nivel2**

pero al momento de ejecutar el sp, me genera el siguiente error

```
ERROR:  no existe la columna «n1_p»
LINE 4:         WHERE id_0 = n1_p :: numeric
                             ^
QUERY:  CREATE VIEW v_nivel_2 AS 
        SELECT gid, id_0, id_1, name_1, geog 
        FROM geografias.nivel2 
        WHERE id_0 = n1_p :: numeric
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL routing.is_foreign_test(bigint,character varying) en la línea 45 en sentencia SQL
NOTICE:  (53)
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL routing.is_foreign_test(bigint,character varying) en la línea 43 en RAISE


Query returned successfully in 850 msec.
```

Answer (score 0):

Del porqué sucede no conozco la respuesta. La solución pasa por generar una sentencia SQL dinámicamente y ejectuar con [execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-execute.html) como explican en [esta respuesta de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132287/creating-a-view-from-a-stored-function-using-that-functions-parameters) en inglés.

```
EXECUTE format('
    CREATE VIEW v_nivel_2 AS 
    SELECT gid, id_0, id_1, name_1, geog 
    FROM geografias.nivel2 
    WHERE id_0 = %s;',
    n1_p);
```